# How to truncate (ö, é etc.) efficiently from R to CSV to HTML?

Tags: html, r, csv, export-to-csv, truncate

I create some data in R (using R studio) that I export as a csv. This cdv will then be uploaded to HTML.

However, I always get bugs with symbols like é and ö and ä.

Is there a way I can "code" accordingly in my R file so in the HTML will look right, i.e. readable like é/ä/ö/ü....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode special characters, eg instead of `ä`, you need to put `&auml;`.

You can find the full list here: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Thank you! I did not know if there is a list all included software understands. Thank you!

Comment: If this solves your problem, it would be highly appreciated if you could upvote & accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: "that all included software understands" -> CSV doesn't care, CSV is simply plain text. But in order for HTML to display special characters, you need to encode them as explained.

Comment: I want to try your solution first and then I am glad to upvote and will surely also accept it! Thank you so much!